# MySQL query to get column names?

Tags: php, mysql

I'd like to get all of a mysql table's col names into an array in php?

Is there a query for this?

Answer (score 618, accepted):

The best way is to use the [INFORMATION_SCHEMA](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-schema.html) metadata virtual database.  Specifically the [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/columns-table.html) table...

```
SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` 
FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` 
WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='yourdatabasename' 
    AND `TABLE_NAME`='yourtablename';
```

It's VERY powerful, and can give you TONS of information without need to parse text (Such as column type, whether the column is nullable, max column size, character set, etc)...

Oh, and it's standard SQL (Whereas `SHOW ...` is a MySQL specific extension)...

For more information about the difference between `SHOW...` and using the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` tables, check out the MySQL [Documentation on `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` in general](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/information-schema.html)...

Comment: It's only standard SQL if you don't use those stupid mysql-specific backticks to quote table names. I hate them, they make my code look wrong.

Comment: @MarkR I actually didn't include them originally when I wrote the answer.  But then it just looked like a wall of black writing.  So I added the back-ticks to take advantage of the syntax highlighting.  Yes, I could have `SET @@SESSION.sql_mode = 'ANSI_QUOTES';` before hand as well, but I really don't like that.  And I have no issue with the back-ticks for identifier delimitation.  In fact, I like them better than double quotes (double quotes makes the query feel wrong to me)...  To each their own...

Comment: Quoting the table names isn't required at all in the above example.

Comment: @MarkR I know it's not.  That's why I said *I actually didn't include them originally when I wrote the answer* .  I added them to take advantage of syntax highlighting...

Comment: Be aware that with InnodDB tables select from information_schema can be very painfully slow. In some servers more than one minute

Comment: @macjohn, see http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2011/12/23/solving-information_schema-slowness/ for a solution to that.

Comment: Using this showed columns that don't exist any more. I'm using `MySql 5.1.68-cll`, the database I'm working of is in bits, so I fell back to @stillstanding answer below

Comment: @Coombesy if that query returned columns, either they exist, or something is **REALLY** broken with your setup. I would *highly* suggest figuring out why it's doing that, and not just using some other syntax.

Comment: @ircmaxell agreed, am on it. project has gone through 3 refactoring stages, with neither finished before the next developer started! A complete mess, looking in to this though is wrongly at the bottom of the task list for next couple of weeks - orders are orders :(

Comment: @Coombesy that's up to you. However I would take indications of possible database corruption as a priority 0 task, and look into it ASAP... But to each their own.

Comment: @ircmaxell agreed - and repeating it for anyone else, this is going to cause unforseen problems down the road if the database is corrupted. Unfortunately its not up to me, I'm a junior programmer and the decision is not mine. Regardless of what I say and have said. So not each to their own, more workers following orders :(

Answer (score 273):

You can use the following query for MYSQL:

```
SHOW `columns` FROM `your-table`;
```

Below is the example code which shows How to implement above syntax in php to list the names of columns:

```
$sql = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM your-table";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $row['Field']."<br>";
}
```

For Details about output of `SHOW COLUMNS FROM TABLE` visit: [MySQL Refrence.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-columns.html)

Comment: Or... `DESC TableName;` ;-)

Comment: Note that `SHOW COLUMNS` is crazy slow and could cause serious performance issues when used since DB engine may recalculate table statistics on every call.

Comment: @stealz Describe seems to be a shortcut to SHOW COLUMNS.

Answer (score 67):

Seems there are 2 ways:

```
DESCRIBE `tablename`
```

or

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM `tablename`
```

More on `DESCRIBE` here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/describe.html

Comment: Ahh, `DESCRIBE` is just a shortcut for `SHOW COLUMNS FROM`.

Comment: And ```DESC``` is even shorter-hand for ```DESCRIBE```!

Comment: Yes @SurrealDreams but with `DESCRIBE` cannot be used with `WHERE`. For example : `SHOW COLUMNS FROM acct__order WHERE ``Key`` = 'PRI';` to get the Primary key of a table is not working with `DESCRIBE`.

Answer (score 27):

I have done this in the past.

```
SELECT column_name
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name='insert table name here';
```

Answer (score 16):

**Edit**: Today I learned the better way of doing this. Please see ircmaxell's answer.

---

Parse the output of `SHOW COLUMNS FROM table;`

Here's more about it here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-columns.html

Answer (score 8):

Use `mysql_fetch_field()` to view all column data.  See [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-field.php).

```
$query = 'select * from myfield';
$result = mysql_query($query);
$i = 0;
while ($i < mysql_num_fields($result))
{
   $fld = mysql_fetch_field($result, $i);
   $myarray[]=$fld->name;
   $i = $i + 1;
}
```

"Warning
This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future."

Comment: `mysqli_num_fields()` and `mysqli_fetch_field_direct()` are the updated methods

Answer (score 7):

**The simplest solution out of all Answers:**

```
DESC `table name`
```

or

```
DESCRIBE `table name`
```

or

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM `table name`
```

Answer (score 7):

this generates a string of column names with a comma delimiter:

```
    SELECT CONCAT('(',GROUP_CONCAT(`COLUMN_NAME`),')') 
    FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` 
    WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='database_name' 
    AND `TABLE_NAME`='table_name';
```

Answer (score 5):

An old PHP function "mysql_list_fields()" is deprecated. So, today the best way to get names of fields is a query "SHOW COLUMNS FROM table_name [LIKE 'name']". So, here is a little example:

```
$fields = array();
$res=mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM mytable");
while ($x = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
  $fields[] = $x['Field'];
}
foreach ($fields as $f) { echo "<br>Field name: ".$f; }
```

Answer (score 5):

when you want to check your all table structure with some filed then use this code. In this query i select column_name,column_type and table_name for more details . I use order by column_type so i can see it easily.

```
SELECT `COLUMN_NAME`,COLUMN_TYPE,TABLE_NAME 
FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` 
WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='yourdatabasename' order by DATA_TYPE;
```

If you want to check only double type filed then you can do it easily

```
SELECT `COLUMN_NAME`,COLUMN_TYPE,TABLE_NAME,DATA_TYPE 
FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` 
WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='yourdatabasename' AND DATA_TYPE like '%bigint%'  order by DATA_TYPE;
```

[image]

if you want to check which field allow null type etc then you can use this

```
SELECT `COLUMN_NAME`,COLUMN_TYPE,TABLE_NAME,IS_NULLABLE,DATA_TYPE 
FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` 
WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='yourdatabasename' and DATA_TYPE like '%bigint%' and IS_NULLABLE ='NO' order by COLUMN_TYPE;
```

[image]

you want to check more then thik link also help you.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/columns-table.html

Comment: Good. Very helpful.

Answer (score 4):

```
function get_col_names(){  
    $sql = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM tableName";  
    $result = mysql_query($sql);     
    while($record = mysql_fetch_array($result)){  
     $fields[] = $record['0'];  
    }
    foreach ($fields as $value){  
      echo 'column name is : '.$value.'-';  
}  
 }  

return get_col_names();
```

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this is what you were looking for, but this worked for me:

```
$query = query("DESC YourTable");  
$col_names = array_column($query, 'Field');
```

That returns a simple array of the column names / variable names in your table or array as strings, which is what I needed to dynamically build MySQL queries. My frustration was that I simply don't know how to index arrays in PHP very well, so I wasn't sure what to do with the results from DESC or SHOW. Hope my answer is helpful to beginners like myself!

To check result:  `print_r($col_names);`

Answer (score 3):

**SHOW COLUMNS** in mysql 5.1 (not 5.5) uses a temporary disk table.

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/internal-temporary-tables.html
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-columns.html

So it can be considered slow for some cases. At least, it can bump up your **created_tmp_disk_tables** value. Imagine one temporary disk table per connection or per each page request.

**SHOW COLUMNS** is not really so slow, possibly because it uses file system cache. Phpmyadmin says ~0.5ms consistently. This is nothing compared to 500ms-1000ms of serving a wordpress page. But still, there are times it matters. There is a disk system involvement, you never know what happens when server is busy, cache is full, hdd is stalled etc.

Retrieving column names through **SELECT * FROM ... LIMIT 1** was around ~0.1ms, and it can use query cache as well.

So here is my little optimized code to get column names from a table, without using **show columns** if possible:

```
function db_columns_ar($table)
{
//returns Array('col1name'=>'col1name','col2name'=>'col2name',...)
if(!$table) return Array();
if(!is_string($table)) return Array();

global $db_columns_ar_cache;
if(!empty($db_columns_ar_cache[$table]))
    return $db_columns_ar_cache[$table];


//IMPORTANT show columns creates a temp disk table
$cols=Array();
$row=db_row_ar($q1="SELECT * FROM `$table` LIMIT 1");
if($row)
    {
    foreach($row as $name=>$val)
        $cols[$name]=$name;
    }
else
    {
    $coldata=db_rows($q2="SHOW COLUMNS FROM `$table`");
    if($coldata)
        foreach($coldata as $row)
            $cols[$row->Field]=$row->Field;
    }
$db_columns_ar_cache[$table]=$cols;
//debugexit($q1,$q2,$row,$coldata,$cols);
return $cols;
}
```

Notes:

- As long as your tables first row does not contain megabyte range of data, it should work fine.
- The function names **db_rows** and **db_row_ar** should be replaced with your specific database setup.

Comment: Hi Johan, I get error: Call to undefined function db_row_ar(), when I run db_columns_ar('myTableName');

Comment: Sorry for that, I will clarify it in text. That was an imaginary function name, standing for whatever your database class or setup uses for that type of thing.

Answer (score 3):

**IN WORDPRESS:**

```
global $wpdb;   $table_name=$wpdb->prefix.'posts';
foreach ( $wpdb->get_col( "DESC " . $table_name, 0 ) as $column_name ) {
  var_dump( $column_name );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this one out I personally use it:

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM $table where field REGEXP 'stock_id|drug_name'
```

Comment: why are you selecting only column names "stock_id" and "drug_name"?

Comment: worked for me but without the "where..." stuff. With PDO:   
  $this->dbHandle = new PDO(...);  
  $query = 'SHOW COLUMNS FROM ' . $tableName;
  $stmt = $this->dbHandle->query($query);
  $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  foreach ($results as $result) {
   //do something with each $result
  }

Answer (score 2):

if you use php, use this **[gist](https://gist.github.com/yantze/bf3aa5a0ec35bebcb8c4)**.

it can get select fields full info with no result，and all custom fields such as:

```
SELECT a.name aname, b.name bname, b.* 
FROM table1 a LEFT JOIN table2 b
ON a.id = b.pid;
```

if above sql return no data,will also get the field names *aname, bname, b's other field name*

just two line:

```
$query_info = mysqli_query($link, $data_source);
$fetch_fields_result = $query_info->fetch_fields();
```

Answer (score 2):

This question is old, but I got here looking for a way to find a given query its field names in a dynamic way (not necessarily only the fields of a table). And since people keep pointing this as the answer for that given task in other related questions, I'm sharing the way I found it can be done, using Gavin Simpson's tips:

```
//Function to generate a HTML table from a SQL query
function myTable($obConn,$sql)
{
    $rsResult = mysqli_query($obConn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($obConn));
    if(mysqli_num_rows($rsResult)>0)
    {
        //We start with header. >>>Here we retrieve the field names<<<
        echo "<table width=\"100%\" border=\"0\" cellspacing=\"2\" cellpadding=\"0\"><tr align=\"center\" bgcolor=\"#CCCCCC\">";
        $i = 0;
        while ($i < mysqli_num_fields($rsResult)){
           $field = mysqli_fetch_field_direct($rsResult, $i);
           $fieldName=$field->name;
           echo "<td><strong>$fieldName</strong></td>";
           $i = $i + 1;
        }
        echo "</tr>"; 
        //>>>Field names retrieved<<<

        //We dump info
        $bolWhite=true;
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rsResult)) {
            echo $bolWhite ? "<tr bgcolor=\"#CCCCCC\">" : "<tr bgcolor=\"#FFF\">";
            $bolWhite=!$bolWhite;
            foreach($row as $data) {
                echo "<td>$data</td>";
            }
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
    }
}
```

This can be easily modded to insert the field names in an array.

Using a simple: `$sql="SELECT * FROM myTable LIMIT 1"` can give you the fields of any table, without needing to use `SHOW COLUMNS` or any extra php module, if needed (removing the data dump part).

Hopefully this helps someone else.

Answer (score 2):

This query fetches a list of all columns in a database without having to specify a table name. It returns a list of only column names:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE table_schema = 'db_name'
```

However, when I ran this query in phpmyadmin, it displayed a series of errors. Nonetheless, it worked. So use it with caution.

Answer (score 2):

if you only need the field names and types (perhaps for easy copy-pasting into Excel):

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='databasenamegoeshere'
AND DATA_TYPE='decimal' and TABLE_NAME = 'tablenamegoeshere'
```

remove

```
DATA_TYPE='decimal'
```

if you want all data types

Answer (score 1):

i no expert, but this works for me..

```
$sql = "desc MyTable";
$result = @mysql_query($sql);
while($row = @mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $row[0]."<br>"; // returns the first column of array. in this case Field

      // the below code will return a full array-> Field,Type,Null,Key,Default,Extra    
      // for ($c=0;$c<sizeof($row);$c++){echo @$row[$c]."<br>";}    

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this query in SQL Server and this worked for me :

```
SELECT name FROM sys.columns WHERE OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID('table_name')
```

Answer (score 0):

The call of `DESCRIBE` is working fine to get all columns of a table but if you need to filter on it, you need to use the `SHOW COLUMNS FROM` instead.

Example of PHP function to get all info of a table :

```
// get table columns (or return false if table not found)
function get_table_columns($db, $table) {
    
    global $pdo;

    if($cols = $pdo->query("DESCRIBE `$db`.`$table`")) {
        if($cols = $cols->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            return $cols;
        }
    }
    
    return false;
}
```

In my case, I had to **find the primary key of a table**. So, I used :

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM `table` WHERE `Key`='PRI';
```

Here is my PHP function :

```
// get table Primary Key
function get_table_pk($db, $table) {

    global $pdo;
            
    $q = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM `$db`.`$table` WHERE `Key` = 'PRI'";
    if($cols = $pdo->query($q)) {
        if($cols = $cols->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            return $cols[0];
        }
    }
    
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Extending to ircmaxell answer, If you ever want to run a select/insert sentence using all the columns from a table (it may be the reason your are browsing this topic, like me) you can use the group_concat function like this:

SELECT group_concat(`COLUMN_NAME`)
FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS`
WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='databaseName'
AND `TABLE_NAME`='tableName';

It will return "field1,field2,field3,fieldN" which is handy for this kind of operations.