# Select Particular column names from a table

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MySQL query to get column names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165195/mysql-query-to-get-column-names)

I need to query the database to get the column/field names, not to be confused with data in the table. For example, if I have a table named `wp_deals` that contains `deal_id, deal_price, creation_date` then I would want to retrieve those field names from the query and nothing else.

so query should be like this

```
select column_names1,column_name2,column_name3 from table_name.
```

Be sure it should only gives those columns names that I want, not all.

Comment: Hint: `USE INFORMATION_SCHEMA; SHOW TABLES;`

Comment: you should usually know such information in advance

Answer (score 1):

Use the `DESCRIBE` command.

```
DESCRIBE `table_name`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do like this:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME1, COLUMN_NAME2 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'my_table';
```

OR

```
SHOW columns FROM my-table;
```

Read more....

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/columns-table.html

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` 
FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` 
WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='yourdatabasename' 
    AND `TABLE_NAME`='yourtablename';
```

Credits: @ ircmaxell

Reference: [This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165195/mysql-query-to-get-column-names)

Comment: i think it will work.it is the best answer.Let me try..

Answer (score 0):

Try this and check this link [**COLUMNS Table**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/columns-table.html):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME) 
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbName' AND TABLE_NAME = 'tableName';
```