# Mysql Select Specific Column with N Column

Tags: mysql

Let's say i have 'db_institute' and 'tb_data' which have 39 Column

While [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21554661/select-last-n-of-columns-of-a-table-from-mysql) Answers Selecting from the last 10 column, i want to add extra column in the query

the result would be like this when i prepared statement it

```
SELECT Name,lastcolumn1,...,lastcolumn10 from tb_data
```

And here's my failed attempt

```
    SELECT Name,
      CONCAT('SELECT ', 
             GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME), 
             ' FROM 'tb_data') 
    FROM 
      (SELECT 
        COLUMN_NAME, 
        ORDINAL_POSITION 
      FROM 
        INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
      WHERE 
        TABLE_SCHEMA='db_institute' 
        AND 
        TABLE_NAME='tb_data' 
      ORDER BY 
        ORDINAL_POSITION DESC LIMIT 10) AS ord_desc 
    ORDER BY 
      ord_desc.ORDINAL_POSITION
  into @sql
```

Which result error

```
Unknown column 'Name' in 'field list'
```

Comment: make sure there is no typo - too many ' quote mark near `' FROM 'tb_data'`. if error still persist, let us know. also why do you have `SELECT Name` while you dont have any reference to that `Name` column, remove it maybe?

Comment: @BoykeFerdinandes i want to select 10 last column with column(Name)
so that makes 11 column selected

Comment: what value do you expect to see from `SELECT Name` ? last 10 columns should be covered by the link you mentioned

Comment: oh `Name` is from tb_data ? my bad didnt get you in the beginning, I'll post an answer soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your reference is already correct. try this

```
SELECT 
  CONCAT('SELECT Franchisee, ', GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME), ' FROM product_staging') # change product_staging to your table name and Franchisee to Name
FROM 
  (SELECT 
    COLUMN_NAME, 
    ORDINAL_POSITION 
  FROM 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
  WHERE 
    TABLE_SCHEMA='myob' # change it to your schema name
    AND 
    TABLE_NAME='product_staging' # change it to your table name
  ORDER BY 
    ORDINAL_POSITION DESC LIMIT 10) AS ord_desc 
ORDER BY 
  ord_desc.ORDINAL_POSITION
INTO @qry;
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @qry;
EXECUTE stmt1;
```