# Query to select specific column in phpmyadmin?

Tags: mysql

I want to show column expect column number 1 
for example = select * from table; this query will show all column

column1 column2 column3 ...

but my question is how to show all column expect column1, so the result will be like this
column2 column3 ...

I don't want to use select column2, column3 from table because that query not efective if my column more than 3. thank

Comment: Possible duplicate of [select first N columns of MySQL table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17258970/select-first-n-columns-of-mysql-table)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL exclude a column using SELECT \* \[except columnA\] FROM tableA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729197/sql-exclude-a-column-using-select-except-columna-from-tablea)

Answer (score -1):

You can select the column after SELECT:

```
SELECT * FROM table
```

`*` means ALL columns, so:

```
SELECT columnName, columName2 FROM table
```

Comment: That does not help to select **all** columns but one, unless you list all of them by hand, which the OP does not want to do