# How do I get database column names in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

How can I get column names of a table in an array or object in Laravel 4, using Schema, DB, or Eloquent?

It seems that I can't find a ready to use function, maybe you have some custom implementations.

Comment: You might have to do a [raw query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165195/mysql-query-to-get-column-names)

Comment: Note that solutions below may change when Laravel hits 4.1, as it removed Doctrine (and thus Doctrine's Schema classes) as a dependency

Comment: Can't believe Laravel does not already provides this feature, CodeIgniter have it. Where I can submit a request for this functionality in Laravel ?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

#### New Answer

At the time I gave this answer **Laravel hadn't a way to do this directly**, but now you can just:

```
$columns = Schema::getColumnListing('users');
```

#### Old Answer

Using attributes won't work because if you do

```
$model = new ModelName;
```

You have no attributes set to that model and you'll get nothing.

Then there is still no real option for that, so I had to go down to the database level and this is my BaseModel:

```
<?php

class BaseModel extends \Eloquent {

    public function getAllColumnsNames()
    {
        switch (DB::connection()->getConfig('driver')) {
            case 'pgsql':
                $query = "SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = '".$this->table."'";
                $column_name = 'column_name';
                $reverse = true;
                break;

            case 'mysql':
                $query = 'SHOW COLUMNS FROM '.$this->table;
                $column_name = 'Field';
                $reverse = false;
                break;

            case 'sqlsrv':
                $parts = explode('.', $this->table);
                $num = (count($parts) - 1);
                $table = $parts[$num];
                $query = "SELECT column_name FROM ".DB::connection()->getConfig('database').".INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'".$table."'";
                $column_name = 'column_name';
                $reverse = false;
                break;

            default: 
                $error = 'Database driver not supported: '.DB::connection()->getConfig('driver');
                throw new Exception($error);
                break;
        }

        $columns = array();

        foreach(DB::select($query) as $column)
        {
            $columns[] = $column->$column_name;
        }

        if($reverse)
        {
            $columns = array_reverse($columns);
        }

        return $columns;
    }

}
```

Use it doing:

```
$model = User::find(1);

dd( $model->getAllColumnsNames() );
```

Comment: I don't have access to mysql here, so I tested it using http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/066acd/2. Could you, please, manually run 'SHOW COLUMNS FROM <yourtablename>' in your mysql?

Comment: Just fixed for MySQL.

Comment: worked now, thx, i accept it since it was the first working answer, but @ceejayoz's answer also is working, with some adjustments for the enum type, thx to all.

Comment: At the time I gave this answer Laravel hadn't a way to do this directly. Answer edited.

Comment: The DBAL enum was being such a pain in the ass that I went with this method instead. Thanks

Comment: getColumnListing is a protected function; you can't just use it the way you suggest, you have to wrap it.

Comment: When using `$tbl_columns = Schema::getColumnListing('deal');` I got this error: `Trying to get property of non-object` which appears in `.../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Processors/MySqlProcessor.php` on this line: `return array_map(function($r) { return $r->column_name; }, $results);`

Comment: Please tell me what could cause this error in my case?

Comment: This is only valid for v4.1.29 and up. Prior to that, the method was protected.

Answer (score 18):

You may try `Schema::getColumnListing('tablename')`:

```
$columns = Schema::getColumnListing('users'); // users table
dd($columns); // dump the result and die
```

Result would be something like this depending on your table:

```
array (size=12)
  0 => string 'id' (length=2)
  1 => string 'role_id' (length=7)
  2 => string 'first_name' (length=10)
  3 => string 'last_name' (length=9)
  4 => string 'email' (length=5)
  5 => string 'username' (length=8)
  6 => string 'password' (length=8)
  7 => string 'remember_token' (length=14)
  8 => string 'bio' (length=3)
  9 => string 'created_at' (length=10)
  10 => string 'updated_at' (length=10)
  11 => string 'deleted_at' (length=10)
```

Comment: in a namespace don't forget the slash at the start \Schema::getColumnListing('tablename')

Answer (score 15):

You can dig down into DB's Doctrine instance.

```
$columns = DB::connection()
  ->getDoctrineSchemaManager()
  ->listTableColumns('table');

foreach($columns as $column) {
  print $column->getName();
  print $column->getType()->getName();
  print $column->getDefault();
  print $column->getLength();
}
```

**edit:** Doctrine is no longer (as of L4.1) installed by default (it's a 'suggested' rather than 'required' package), but can be added to your `composer.json` as `doctrine/dbal` to retain this functionality.

Comment: Tried that too, but it doesn't work for SQL server: Class 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOSqlsrv\Driver' not found.

Comment: @AntonioCarlosRibeiro I've never used Microsoft SQL Server with Doctrine, so you're on your own there. A raw query is probably your best bet if that's your underlying tech. The OP is using MySQL, though.

Comment: This solution works, one thing to mention, if the table contains enum type , it throws this exception. Unknown database type enum requested, Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\MySqlPlatform may not support it.

Comment: @Centurion Laravel doesn't technically support enums at all - you can't create one via the Schema manager.

Comment: @ceejayoz based on docs i created one, http://laravel.com/docs/schema, $table->enum('choices', array('foo', 'bar')); ENUM equivalent to the table, the truth is that Doctrine is not supporting them.

Comment: Huh, I don't remember that being there for 4.0. Maybe it's a 4.1 thing? Neato. Related issue: https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/2133

Answer (score 1):

I think there's a couple different options, if you are using an Eloquent model, you can look at the [`getAccessibleAttributes()`](http://laravel.com/api/source-class-Illuminate.Database.Eloquent.Model.html#_getAccessibleAttributes) method, which in theory would give you all the columns of a model consider Eloquent seems them as properties.

For example, you'd be able to do something like this for your users table on a User Eloquent model.

```
$user = // Retrieve your User model.
$columns = User->getAccessibleAttributes();
```

Another Eloquent method to look at that's similar, but doesn't have the 'accessibility' requirement is the [`attributesToArray()`](http://laravel.com/api/source-class-Illuminate.Database.Eloquent.Model.html#_attributesToArray) method.  The returned array of which should have your columns as a key.  Then you can use the PHP function `array_keys()` to build an array of the keys, which would be your columns.

```
$user = // Retrieve your User model.
$columns = array_keys(User::attributesToArray());
```

Comment: $columns = array_keys(User::attributesToArray());
gives an Exception Non-static method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::attributesToArray() should not be called statically

Comment: You should be doing it with your actual user object. For example, `$admin->attributesToArray()`.

Comment: @MikeAnthony yes, it is not a static method, I did not realize.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: @Sajan Parikh even if instantiated, still not working, returning an empty array (

Answer (score 1):

I know it might not be the answer for everyone, but maybe you can grab one record, and get all keys of the data. Ex.

```
array_keys(User::first()->toArray());
```

Comment: This works great if you have partial views dependent on many different models.

Comment: Won't work properly if you have  some columns hidden or masked.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Model instance you can retrieve like following:

```
    $table_name = $model->getTable();
    $connection = $model->getConnection();
    $schemaBulder = $connection->getSchemaBuilder();

    $columns_array = $schemaBulder->getColumnListing($table_name);
```

works for Laravel 5

Answer (score -1):

You also can try this:

```
abstract class BaseModel extends Eloquent {

public function getColumnsNames()
{
    $connection = DB::connection();
    $connection->getSchemaBuilder();

    $table   = $connection->getTablePrefix() . $this->table;
    $grammar = $connection->getSchemaGrammar();
    $results = $connection->select($grammar->compileColumnExists(), array($connection->getDatabaseName(), $table));

    return $connection->getPostProcessor()->processColumnListing($results);
}
}
```

Comment: This isn't working for me. The debugger says:

    $grammar->compileColumnExists($table) = "select column_name from information_schema.columns where table_schema = ? and table_name = ?"

It's not substituting the values in the query when it compiles...what am I missing?

Comment: Can you past in somewhere a example of how are you using it? The idea here is to use this only in your model classes. Wich they will have the table property setted. Also this working for me in a 4.1.* laravel app, may this have to change in more recent versions.

Comment: I update the code making the BaseModel abscract, to force a implementation.

Answer (score -1):

I use SQL Server and the Schema way worked for me:

```
$columns = array_keys(Schema::getConnection()
->getDoctrineSchemaManager()
->listTableColumns($yourModel->getTable()) );
```

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted, I guess I should have mentioned you may need Doctrine.