# How to get keys name from array in laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-4

I want to get my table's column name. when i use model::all();

```
Users::all();

Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Object 
(
    [items:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => Users Object
                (
                    [table:protected] => users
                    [hidden:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => password
                            [1] => remember_token
                        )

                    [fillable] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [connection:protected] => 
                    [primaryKey:protected] => id
                    [perPage:protected] => 15
                    [incrementing] => 1
                    [timestamps] => 1
                    [attributes:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [first_name] => Mohammed Saqib
                            [last_name] => Rajput
                            [email] => rajput.saqib@hotmail.com
                            [dob] => 2015-06-18 00:00:00
                            [mobile] => 03006710419
                            [status] => inactive
                        )

                    [original:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [first_name] => Mohammed Saqib
                            [last_name] => Rajput
                            [email] => rajput.saqib@hotmail.com
                            [dob] => 2015-06-18 00:00:00
                            [mobile] => 03006710419
                            [status] => inactive
                        )

                    [relations:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [visible:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [appends:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [guarded:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => *
                        )

                    [dates:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [touches:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [observables:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [with:protected] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [morphClass:protected] => 
                    [exists] => 1
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can make use of `array_keys` to get all attributes from a model.

```
$users = Users::all();
$user = $users->first();
$attributes = array_keys($user->toArray());
```

Alternatively you can use [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19953826/1903366) to get the column names based from a certain table in your database.

Comment: want to get key with where the collection is that possible???

$collection = Tracking::confirmedNotDel()
            ->groupBy('oppor_id')
            ->selectRaw('oppor_id, sum(logged_mins)/60 as logged_hours')
            ->get();


        $collection = collect($collection);
        $data       = $collection->where('oppor_id', $oppr->id);
        dd($data); //key of that object as i want to get row number

Answer (score 19):

Now you can just use the `->keys()` method from a collection.

```
$fruits = collect(['orange' => 15, 'lemon' => 75]);

$keys = $fruits->keys();

// ['orange', 'lemon']
```

See more at https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#method-keys