# Trying to get all column names in a table

Tags: php, laravel

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19951787/laravel-4-get-column-names) answer which says to do like this:

```
$columns = Schema::getColumnListing('users');
```

But it doesnt say what to use, but I suppose it should be:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Builder as Schema;
```

But when I try it it doesnt work:

```
$columns = Schema::getColumnListing("users");
```

I get error:

> Non-static method Illuminate\Database\Schema\Builder::getColumnListing() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context

Comment: What version are you using? This method was protected until v4.1.29

Comment: @d0ug7a5 Laravel 5.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
$columns = DB::getSchemaBuilder()->getColumnListing('users');
```

And `use DB;` to import the needed dependencies.

Comment: Thanks! I would've never figured out!

Answer (score 2):

To address the initial problem, the reason why it did not work for you is because you should have simply used this:

```
use Schema;
```

instead of this:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Builder as Schema;
```

Comment: I had no ide I could just do use Schema. Dont I have to add a path to the classes? Where is shema?

Comment: By using `use Schema;` you are calling a Facade. Laravel provides plenty of those. Just take a look here: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/facades