# How to get table column names as array from model

Tags: laravel

I'm new to laravel

I have `post` table, this table has 10 columns.

So i want to get all column names in model
Laravel Does this feature already work??

Or do I have to make it myself ??

Any suggestion or advice would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to get all column names in a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31069859/trying-to-get-all-column-names-in-a-table)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `getColumnListing()` method:

```
use Schema;
Schema::getColumnListing($this->getTable())
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$columns = Schema::getColumnListing('posts');
dd($columns);
```