# MYSQL select * from table, including column names

Tags: mysql

Is there an easy way to "SELECT * FROM TABLE" , but also include the column names in the first row?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: You better handle that in your program logic.

Comment: are you using this query in your programming script?

Comment: Refer this: [MYSQL select * from table, including column names](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4165253)

Comment: Plenty of fiddles to do it, but how would SQL cope when responding to a query from a strictly typed language, trying to put a column name into a numeric field?

Answer (score 1):

MySQL does not deliver the column names as a row, but it certanly does deliver them.
You can set the connection type to associative (instead of indexed) to get results like `'id' => 123` instead of `[0] => 123`.

Since every result set (row) contains the names as array keys, you can get them with array_keys($row) (PHP-syntax, others alike). This is the most common procedure to build e.g. CSV files.