# How to find columns in mysql that starts with certain strings

Tags: mysql

I have a table "myTable" with lots of columns with one column called "listing_id".

I want to find the listings that start with "CG_"

Also I will like to have count how many such are there?

Comment: You're using MySQL wrong. You **know** columns you need. You don't **ask** for columns, then select. Consider alternate permanent storage, something like Mongo or other types that don't have a schema. MySQL or RDBMS aren't for this usage scenario, unless you use EAV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select count(listing_id)
from mytable
where listing_id like 'CG_%';
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say you can use the information_schema as 
explained in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165195/mysql-query-to-get-column-names).

```
SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` 
FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` 
WHERE `COLUMN_NAME` like 'CG_%';
```

Answer (score 0):

unclear what are you asking..Thos query select all string like `cg_%` under `listing_id`

> I want to find the listings that start with "CG_"
>
> Also I will like to have count how many such are there?column

```
SELECT count(listing_id)
FROM tablename
WHERE listing_id LIKE 'cg_%'
```