# mysql - retrieve specific column name from table

Tags: php, mysql

I'm begginer in MYSQL.
I need to retrieve the COLUMN NAMES of columns which have value "TRUE"?
I found this code but I don't understand how to user it:

```
 SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` 
 FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` 
 WHERE `TABLE_NAME`='tablename'
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: just use `desc tablename` . To find the columns in the table.

Comment: @user3411648 How does this answer the question?

Comment: What he is asking and desc table are the same . You cant search by column in database .

Comment: @user3411648 Granted, his original question is a little ambiguous and possibly he doesn't understand that columns != rows, but to me it seems like he is looking to find any column names that have a value of 'TRUE' in the rows of the table.

Comment: **" he is looking to find any column names that have a value of 'TRUE' in the rows of the table. "** Yes, that's what I need

Answer (score 1):

I think this will help you [MySQL query to get column names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165195/mysql-query-to-get-column-names)

With the following you will get all information about the specific column

```
SELECT * 
FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` 
WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='yourdatabasename' 
    AND `TABLE_NAME`='yourtablename';
    AND `COLUMN_NAME` = 'namecolumn'
```

If you want the names of all columns which have the value true in a row you could use foreach if you use php and write all keys in an array for example where the value is true

```
$list = array();
foreach($rows as $key => $value)
{
   if($value === true) $list[] = $key;
}
```

Comment: That does not answer the original question.

Comment: isn't he searching for all columns named true?

Answer (score 0):

This code shows all column names from a specific table, the schema INFORMATION_SCHEMA stores information about the items created on your database server(schemas, tables, columns etc.)

The statement above will show you alle columns from `tablename`, theres also a more simple syntax to do this `SHOW COLUMNS FROM tablename` ([MySQL Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-columns.html))

How do you want to determine that the value of a column is true? Maybe there a two rows in your table with the values TRUE and FALSE for one column (TRUE in one row and FALSE in the other row)

**With one Row in PHP**

If there is only one row in your table execute the `SHOW COLUMNS FROM tablename` do a `fetch_array` on the result and then foreach and save only the keys where the value is TRUE.

If you try to store something like a configuration use a key value table and query it using where clause, this will be more effective.