# Retrieve MySQL column names when no rows are returned

Tags: php, mysql

Wondering if there's a way to get MySQL to return the column names when the query result returns no rows? The issue is that our system has multiple large queries sometimes:

```
SELECT * FROM table

SELECT table1.*, table2.field1, table2.field2

SELECT table1.field1 AS f1, SUM(table2.field1) AS f2
```

etc. So only way to get the column names when the returned result is empty, would be to parse the queries, and attempt to run a query on the information_schema table. Which is possible, but would be rather complex. Any ideas?

Comment: How do you expect to handle differences in data types? e.g. can you anticipate receiving 'myDateColumn' instead of a date object?

Comment: @raina77ow: referred [MySQL query to get column names?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165195/mysql-query-to-get-column-names) isn`t answer to this question, as this question is about how to get column names from **query**, not **table**

Comment: @Rimas Fair point, voting for reopen.

Answer (score 4):

Some PHP interfaces for MySQL have a function for result set metadata, which should return information even for a result set with zero rows.

- MySQLi has [mysqli_stmt::result_metadata()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.result-metadata.php).
- PDO has [PDOStatement::getColumnMeta()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.getcolumnmeta.php), but it's labeled "experimental," which probably just means it's not well tested in all PDO drivers.

Answer (score 0):

One technique that you can use is to create a view on the query and then query `information_schema` with the view name.

That is, something like this:

```
create view v_JustForColumns as
    <your query here>;

select *
from information_schema.columns
where table_name = 'v_JustForColumns';

drop view v_JustForColumns;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below one. Here replace the YOUR_SCHEMA with your actual schema name and YOUR_TABLENAME with your actual table name:

```
select column_name from information_schema.columns  
where not exists(select * from YOUR_SCHEMA.YOUR_TABLENAME) 
and  table_name='YOUR_TABLENAME';
```