# join a same table with different tables

Tags: sql, join

I am wondering if anyone can help me, I have these tables:

```
tbl_search_history(id,fld_user_id,fld_username_fld_make_id,fld_model_id,fld_year_id,fld_category_id)
```

The `fld_make` is the name of the make:

```
tbl_make(id,fld_make)
```

The `fld_model` is the name of that model

```
tbl_model(id,fld_model)
```

The `fld_year` is the name of that year

```
tbl_year(id, fld_year)
```

The `fld_category` is the name of that category

```
tbl_category(id,fld_category)
```

Now I need to show a table in my page in which I need to have this fields: `make`, `model`, `year`, and `category`.  I also want to know how can I have the `make`, `model`, `year`, and category names (instead of just the reference numbers from the `tbl_search_history`) in my page? Would you please give me a piece of code and a brief explanation?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please show us your code and tell us what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a bit unclear, but it sounds like a homework problem. 
I will give you some pseudocode and references. 
First off I would do some reading on [JOINS](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp). 
If you are asking to get Column Names, see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165195/mysql-query-to-get-column-names) 
I believe what you want to do is join your tables like so:

```
SELECT table1.desired_field, table2.desired_field2, table3.desired_field3
FROM table1
JOIN table2 ON table1.table2_id = table2.id
JOIN table3 ON table1.table3_id = table3.id
```

and so on.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    tbl_model.fld_make,
    tbl_make.fld_model,
    tbl_year.fld_year,
    tbl_category.fld_category
FROM
    tbl_search_history
    INNER JOIN tbl_make ON tbl_search_history.fld_make_id = tbl_make.id
    INNER JOIN tbl_model ON tbl_search_history.fld_model_id = tbl_model.id
    INNER JOIN tbl_year ON tbl_search_history.fld_year_id = tbl_year.id
    INNER JOIN tbl_category ON tbl_search_history.fld_category_id = tbl_category.id
```

Assuming that the search history table is the table that links all these other tables together.  Also assuming that all of these tables have linked values (ie non-null id's in tbl_search_history) otherwise you'd need to use an OUTER JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is to join with the `make`, `model`, `year`, and `category` tables using the `id`s you have in the `tbl_search_history`.

Something of this sort will give you want you want :

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_search_history`
INNER JOIN `tbl_make`
    ON tbl_search_history.fld_make_id = tbl_make.id
#keep going for model, year, and category tables using their respective ids.
```

Hope this helps!