# Extract columns names resulting by query

Tags: mysql

is it possible to get the columns names resulting by a query?

So (for example) if I have this query:

```
SELECT Id AS IdNumber, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tab2 WHERE IdRif = T1.Id) AS TotCount 
FROM tab1 T1
```

I'd like to get:

```
IdNumber
TotCount
```

I saw [MySQL query to get column names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165195/mysql-query-to-get-column-names) (and also other questions) but I wasn't able to use it for what I need.

Comment: What do you want to get? Column names of a query, not a table? Why? You already have them inside the query.

Comment: It may appear strange but I have a complex query and I get confused when I need to use the values in the array who gets query values. So If I can get columns names I'll work more easily (I'm not a pro)

Comment: Are you using PHP along with MySQL ? To work on the Query result.

Comment: @genespos In both php and perl you can get the results into a hash. Keys of the hash will be column names. So, no need for a special query. What language/library do you use?

Comment: I'm using Excel-VBA but, if possible, I'd like to use an SQL code to get columns names. In any case a vba code can be useful.

Comment: In VBA I get data from query in an array with `myData = rs.getrows` (where 'rs' is my recordset) and I can get fields names with `Set myFields = rs.Fields`. But myFields is an Object and to get fields names in an array I'll need more code (and I cannot use debug window).  What I need is to know the position of a certain field so to insert the exact index while coding. So, in the example above, when I'll need to call the "TotCount" I'll need to know that It's in "myData(1,x)" . This is why I'd like using mysql: I wish to see the field names (and their numbers) on screen.

Answer (score 0):

If your query returns results just use the object(fetch_object) / array (fetch_assoc) from the row and use `array_keys($row)`

if no rows are returned use http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-field-direct.php

```
$result = $db->query($sql);
$i = 0;
while ($i < $db->field_count) {
    $info = $result->fetch_field_direct($i++);
    echo $info->name;
}
```

as an example

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the query result into an Associative Array using `mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)` or `$result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)` or whatever method you are using, so that the `Key=>Value` pair of your Associative Array would be your `ColumnName=>ColumnValue`.

So, irrespective of whether you are using `mysql` or `mysqli`, you would be using the same logic to get the column names.