# MySQL Select data without column name

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Suppose

```
SELECT * FROM some_tbl;
```

is same as

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM some_tbl;
```

Then how can I get the data from some_tbl without column name?

The problem is I don't know the column names...

Even I can't use *information_schema* in security reason...

Somebody said to me

> You can get data without specific column name.

But I have any idea about it.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM some_tbl;` is selecting all of the columns in a table. I'm not sure what you're asking. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Question's a bit vague. Are you trying to do this using a particular programming language, or from the command line, or... ?

Comment: maybe you can get columns names : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165195/mysql-query-to-get-column-names

Comment: What language / client API are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you're after, but

```
SELECT * FROM some_tbl LIMIT 0;
```

will produce an empty result set containing the names of all the columns. Most decent APIs will allow you to access these column names from the result set.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for:

```
Select * from syscolumns where ID in 
(Select ID from sysobjects where name = 'some_tbl')
```