# How to print fields of a table of mysql

Tags: php, mysql

```
$fld_one ='SHOW COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE SCHEMA = '.$dbone'.'AND TABLE NAME = '.$tbone.'';

SHOW COLUMNS FROM $tbone FROM mydb;
```

Comment: I have tried both the codes but its not printing unique fields of a particular table

Comment: you're probably looking for a SELECT syntax, but whatever it is, your question is unreadable and unprecise, and pretty obvious you didnt make any effort to look for widely known and described solutions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL query to get column names?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165195/mysql-query-to-get-column-names)

Comment: Is that formatted correctly? Seems to be off.. maybe pseudo code?

Answer (score 2):

Its query gives the all column_name

```
SELECT group_concat(column_name) 
FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_schema = 'DB_NAME' AND table_name = 'TABLE_NAME'
```

Answer (score 0):

This should hopefully do what you want.

```
$sql="select `column_name` 
from `information_schema`.`columns` 
where `table_schema`=database() and `table_name`='$tbone';";
```