# Decrypt data from MySQL database

Tags: php, html, mysql, salt

I have the below code to show all data from a MySQL database in a HTMl database:

```
<?php
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Persons");
echo "<table border='1'>";
$i = 0;
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    if ($i == 0) {
      $i++;
      echo "<tr>";
      foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
        echo "<th>" . $key . "</th>";
      }
      echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach ($row as $value) {
      echo "<td>" . $value . "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

This code works fine and the data is displayed in the table correctly, my problem is that most of the data in the DB is encrypted (simply)!

For example, here is how someones first name is stored `5cGs+mhdNN/SnHdqEbMk6zlKRu8uW7pR1zRjQHV9DGQ=`

Is there a way to decrypt the data before displaying it in the table?

I usually decrpyt the date in the following way:

```
$name_firstD = simple_decrypt($name_first , "secured");
```

Comment: Salts ecnrpytion are one way only You can not decrypt

Comment: It may not be salt then sorry

Comment: First you need to decrypt your entire database, to avoid double decryption. Then change your logic to not encrypt anymore.

Comment: that's not encrypted. that looks like `base_64`.

Comment: @FelippeDuarte  What do you mean?

Comment: **Just a small point:** As `simple_decrypt()` is not standard PHP I had never heard of it. I imagine many others had not either. A quick note in your question about what it was would have been helpful

Comment: @RyanVincent See [Documentation](http://earlysandwich.com/programming/simple-php-encrypt-decrypt-functions-81/) its already being done in the function. **Yup I had never heard of it either** Oh actually its getting done in the wrong place!!!!

Comment: @RiggsFolly,  I learn something new about PHP rather more often  than I would like ;-/ Those do look like useful functions though :). Thanks for the link.

Comment: @RyanVincent It seems to work. Except that the default `salt` generates a silly error because its one byte too long

Comment: Don't use `simple_encrypt` it is not using AES but another version of Rijndael. It is also using ECB mode which is not secure yet creating an iv that ECB mode does not use. The `$salt` is really the encryption key and no checks are made nor key extension used. What a mess. Sure it answers the question "Is encryption used" but fails the question "Is it secure." Instead consider using [defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption), it is being maintained and is correct/secure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have an array of columns which are encrypted.

```
<?php
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Persons");

$encrypted_columns = array('password','code', 'first_name');

echo "<table border='1'>";
$i = 0;
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    if ($i == 0) {
      $i++;
      echo "<tr>";
      foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
        echo "<th>" . $key . "</th>";
      }
      echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
      echo "<td>" . (in_array($key,$encrypted_columns))? simple_decrypt($value , "secured") : $value . "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

put the name of your encrypted column inside $encrypted_columns array.

Comment: @user3092953. It should work. unless the information you provided is wrong. Please review the code and customize it with your proper values