# display results of mysqli_multi_query in table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, html-table

I am trying to echo the results of two queries into a table.  It seems to be splitting the results into separate rows rather than beside each other.  The values for spaceid and venueid match in the db.

Here is my code:

```
 <?php
$con=mysqli_connect("host","username","pword","mydb");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$sql = "SELECT venue.venuename FROM venue INNER JOIN space ON space.spaceID=venue.venueID;";
$sql .= "SELECT space.room, space.costoftables FROM space INNER JOIN venue ON space.spaceID=venue.venueID;";
?>
<table class="tablesorter" width="600px" border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" id="myTable">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Venue Name</th>  <th>Room</th> <th>Cost</th>
</tr></thead><tbody>
<?php
// Execute multi query
if (mysqli_multi_query($con,$sql)){
  do{
      // Store first result set
    if ($result=mysqli_store_result($con)) {
      // Fetch one and one row
      while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$row['venuename']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['room']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['costoftables']."</td>";
        }
        ?>
        </tr>
        <?php

      }
    }
  while (mysqli_next_result($con));
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Here is the result:
[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iO5Dk.png)

Comment: you have `echo "<tr>";` inside the loop and `</tr>` outside the loop

Comment: I put it inside the loop but it still isn't working

Comment: you put "what" exactly inside the loop, just `</tr>` or `echo "</tr>";`? Two different animals here.

Comment: you also need an other group of tr's to match the number of columns

Comment: I put echo "</tr>";

Comment: I have another group of tr's at the top for the table headers - is this what you mean?  Or do I need more? If so, where exactly?  Thank you

Comment: have a look at this Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17902483/show-values-from-a-mysql-database-table-inside-a-html-table-in-a-page and base yourself on that. You'll get it going ;-) and this too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37574299/display-all-mysql-table-data-in-html-table

Comment: I did base it off that.. unfortunately it's still not working :(