# Wordpress - export a mysql table to csv with column headers

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, export-to-csv

I am able to download a file in csv format for my table , but how to add column headers to the same file .

The current code is following -

```
// load wpdb
    $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
    include_once $path . '/wp-load.php';

     global $wpdb;

   $table = $_POST["table_name"];// table name
   $file = 'database_csv'; // csv file name
   $results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->prefix$table",ARRAY_A );

   if(count($results) > 0){
      foreach($results as $result){
      $result = array_values($result);
      $result = implode(", ", $result);
      $csv_output .= $result."\n";
    }
  }

  $filename = $file."_".date("Y-m-d_H-i",time());
  header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
  header("Content-disposition: csv" . date("Y-m-d") . ".csv");
  header( "Content-disposition: filename=".$filename.".csv");
  header("Pragma: no-cache");
  header("Expires: 0");
  print $csv_output;
  exit;
```

Comment: `$csv_output = "Column1;Column2;Column3;"`?

Comment: @u_mulder i want to dynamically get column names for automating this :)

Comment: Then use search. I've found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165195/mysql-query-to-get-column-names

Comment: @u_mulder is there any wordpress function for same ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with WP so I dont know

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it by first getting column names and then assigning it to final output :

```
  $table_name = $wpdb->prefix.$_POST["table_name"];// table name
                       $file = 'database_csv'; // csv file name
                       $results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $table_name",ARRAY_A );

                        // get column names
                        $query = "SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='".$wpdb->dbname."' AND `TABLE_NAME`='".$table_name."'";

                        $columnNamesList = $wpdb->get_results($query);  


                        foreach ( $columnNamesList as $column_name ) {
                            $csv_output.=$column_name->COLUMN_NAME.",";
                        }


                        // remove last additional comma 
                        $csv_output = substr($csv_output,0,strlen($csv_output)-1);

                        // start dumping csv rows in new line
                        $csv_output.="\n";

                       if(count($results) > 0){
                          foreach($results as $result){
                          $result = array_values($result);
                          $result = implode(", ", $result);
                          $csv_output .= $result."\n";
                        }
                      }

                      $filename = $file."_".date("Y-m-d_H-i",time());
                      header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
                      header("Content-disposition: csv" . date("Y-m-d") . ".csv");
                      header( "Content-disposition: filename=".$filename.".csv");
                      header("Pragma: no-cache");
                      header("Expires: 0");
                      print $csv_output;
                      exit;
```