# Get Column Names with SQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

how can I get the column names without explicitly asking for it?

I have this SQL query.

```
SELECT * FROM Machines WHERE id='$id'
```

Is it possible to get the column names through a PHP function? Something like this:

```
mysqli_fetch_columns($result)
```

I understand that you can get the column names through a SQL Statement, however this is not practical for me. I would like to retreive the column names through some PHP function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL query to get column names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165195/mysql-query-to-get-column-names)

Comment: @JohnHC As I stated in my question, _without explicitly asking for it_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
include 'connection.php';

$result = $connection->query("select * from users");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_field($result)) {
    $array[] = $row;
}
```

In $array you will get all column name