# how to count particluar columns and display tha data in table according to the count value in mysql php pdo?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have one table in MySQL which is post_data.  consists of fields like `(uname, pass, email, cam_name,cam_img, cam_model etc..)` when user registered my website some fields get updated like `(uname, pass, email)` and other fields are empty.but in another page I want to display `(cam_img, cam_name)` fields based on the columns count in the page.

my code in index.php:

---

```
$stmt = $index_home->getDetails();

if($stmt->rowCount() > 0)
{

    while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        extract($row);
    }
        ?>
```

getDetails implentation in USER  class

---

```
public function getDetails()
{
try
{
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare('SELECT userID, user_name, cam_name, cam_model, cam_rent, cam_img, mobile FROM post_data ORDER BY userID DESC');
$stmt->execute();
return $stmt;
}
catch(PDOException $ex)
    {
        echo $ex->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Everything is fine when data is there on selected columns like (cam_name,cam_img etc). But the problem is, when data is not there in those fields it also count all rows in the table. I want to restrict that.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Check the second answer, it might solve your issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165195/mysql-query-to-get-column-names

Comment: i don't want to display column names in webpage...@MammaMia

Comment: When select query count the particular columns row data,, if i contains data return 1 else 0......