# How do I get column name by row in MysQLI?

Tags: php, mysqli

How do I return the column name in mysqli by row?

```
...
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `xtdf` WHERE posterid='bike'"); 
$rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result); 

foreach($rows as $column => $value) {
    echo $column . " " . $value;
}
...
```

This code above will return all columns name and values, but I want only the column name by the value. I have tried this code below but returns nothing.

```
...
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `xtdf` WHERE posterid='bike'"); 
$rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result); 

foreach($rows as $column => $value) {
if ($value == "bike") {
    echo $column;
    }
}
```

Edit: I don't want put the result in *array*, or bring all results. Only return one value.
PHP version: 5.5.15
What should I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL query to get column names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165195/mysql-query-to-get-column-names)

Comment: It isn't. I don't want return ALL tables to array. I want only one without array.

Comment: if I understand you correctly you want to know in which column you have the value 'bike'. But in the query you ask already for `posterid` to be 'bike' - so this would be the column, right? This sounds like an XY Problem to me. What is the actual goal you wanna achieve?

Comment: At this moment I still practicing, but in the future I'll use a loop, so is this the main reason for get the column name

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    foreach($row as $column => $value) {
       if ($value == "bike") {
          echo $column;
       }
    }
}
```

You need to iterate through all values that you fetch from database.

Comment: Unfortunately it still returns nothing

Comment: Could you show us the SQL query? And are you sure that you have a value = "bike", lowercase and trimmed?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/j4ysep At this moment I still practicing, but in the future I'll use a loop, so is this the main reason for get the column name

Comment: You have two lines with `mysql_fetch_array` .. remove the line outside the `while`

Comment: Already did it, also, I have changed the _$row_ of your code to another name just for test it

Comment: Could you update your question with the **actual** code?