# MySQL - Concat all colums in a string

Tags: mysql, select, concatenation, concat-ws

I need to concat all columns in a string of a row.
Something like this can be possible?

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(';', *) FROM db.table
```

Table:

```
|col1   |col2   |col3   |
-------------------------
|val11  |val12  |val13  |
|val21  |val22  |val23  |
```

Result:

```
val11;val12;val13
val21;val22;val23
```

Thanks.

Comment: You need to specify all the columns by name in the concat statement or use dynamic sql (building a sql statement from information_schema.columns)  if you don't want to do that. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html

Comment: If you have so many columns that you don't want to write them down then your table design is most probably wrong.

Comment: @juergend the design of table are realy bad, but that not a my table and are so old

Comment: @P.Salmon okay thanks, so i need to crate a "dynamic" query

Comment: you can make a csv https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html and load that

Comment: You probably need to fix your schema.

Comment: @nbk too long and useless operation

Comment: @Strawberry i can't it's a standard schema for other applications

Comment: @Riccardo then use a stored procedure, use https://stackoverflow.com/a/4165253/5193536 to get all column names and build a sql SELECt with CONCAT and use that with a prepared statement like P.Salmon said