# how to get only name of columns in mysql table?

Tags: mysql

i saw this post [MySQL query to get column names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165195/mysql-query-to-get-column-names)
i try to use this code  `` `table name` `` or `` DESCRIBE `table name` ``  or `` SHOW COLUMNS FROM `table name` ``
but  return me also a datatype and more  in this mode

```
id  int NO auto_increment
```

i  want only a name  id  is  possible have it ?? thanks
somtime is possible bypass  qualitystandard ?? please

Answer (score 1):

use the tables from information_schema to get the meta data of your table:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE table_name = 'tbl_name'
```

For more information see https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19078-01/mysql/mysql-refman-5.0/information-schema.html#columns-table

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like the default output of the SHOW commands, you can get anything you want from the INFORMATION_SCHEMA tables (which is where the SHOW commands get their data too).

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = ? AND TABLE_NAME = ?;
```