# SQLITE: horizontally combining large sql tables based on common entry

Tags: database, sqlite, join, select, organization

I have multiple tables I need to join horizontally based on a common entry. For the first sets of tables, I need to join  tables that look like:

Table 1 dimension = 1093367x18 and It looks like

| ROW # | ID | TEMPERATURE | DESCR | ... | NUMB |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 32 | 23 | Y | ... | 23 |
| 2 | 47 | 54 | N | ... | 24 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 1,093367 | 78 | 12 | Y | ... | 45 |

Table 2 dimension = 1093367x648

| ROW # | ID | COLOR 1 | COLOR 2 | ... | COLOR 648 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 32 | RED | BLUE | ... | GREEN |
| 2 | 47 | BLUE | PURPLE | ... | RED |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 1,093367 | 78 | YELLOW | RED | ... | BLUE |

And I need [Table 1 |Table 2]:

| ROW # | ID | TEMPERATURE | DESCR | ... | NUMB | COLOR 1 | COLOR 2 | ... | COLOR 648 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 32 | 23 | Y | ... | 23 | RED | BLUE | ... | GREEN |
| 2 | 47 | 54 | N | ... | 24 | BLUE | PURPLE | ... | RED |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 1,093367 | 78 | 12 | Y | ... | 45 | YELLOW | RED | ... | BLUE |

Is this possible to do in SQLITE? I have only found solutions in which I would have to type out all 648 columns for table 2. Is this the only way to do this in SQLITE?

Comment: The correct answer gives you a Standard SQL statement, that you can use as a subquery to find all column names in your table. Please check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165195/mysql-query-to-get-column-names

Comment: Im getting the error : [10:55:23] Error while executing SQL query on database 'my_database': no such table: INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS. Do I have to download a package for this? I've googled this to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to write any column name in the `SELECT` statement if you do a join with the `USING` clause instead of the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2
USING(id);
```

This will return all the columns of the 2 tables (first Table1's rows and then Table2's rows) but the columns used in the `USING` clause (in this case the column `id` on which the join is based) will be returned only once.

You can find more about the `USING` clause in [Determination of input data (FROM clause processing)](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#determination_of_input_data_from_clause_processing_).

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=1ba95d22e89dbc789e4a2ed7a6788391).

Comment: Is there a way to do this with more than 2 tables, or should I export the results and add the next table using this same method?

Comment: @anni check this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=631447b7380caf821b126e2b945be106